# How do I add documentation to lightning bundle in Force.com IDE?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-ide

I'm using Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) with the Force.com Plugin version 37.0.0.201609220436. When I create a new Lightning Bundle, "myComponent" I get:

- myComponent.cmp
- myComponent.cmp-meta.xml
- myComponentController.js
- myComponentHelper.js

I don't see a way to add the *.auradoc member from the IDE. When I create the "Documentation" from the Dev Console, and refresh my IDE from the server, the *.auradoc member is there.

Is it possible to create those "other" members (Style, Documentation, Renderer, etc...) of a Lightning Bundle from Eclipse + Plugin?

Comment: Did you try creating a file in the folder of the bundle directly and use the same naming convention and file extension .Example for design file it will be .design and for CSS it will be .CSS etc

Comment: I haven't tried, and I think that would probably work. But chances are that **I** would do something like misspell the filename somehow and break the bundle. I'm still hoping for Dev Console-like functionality in the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the product manager for Force.com IDE. To create files within a bundle, there are no templates at the moment. While in the bundle folder, right click New > File. Then enter a name like Charts.auradoc.

In a future release or patch, we may change the new bundles to include all file types so this is more intuitive.

These are the acceptable file types:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]